# Get Unix date (numeric) from string and convert to Python date

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract a unix date from a rather large body of text returned on a url link so Ive used:

```
link = Open_URL(url)
match=re.compile('"Date":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
```

But when I print the unix date its a large number rather than a date, I need to convert it to a usable date format, I tried:

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(int(my)ints)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But it wont allow me to convert a link, any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Current code:

```
link = Open_URL(url)
match=re.compile('"End Date":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
for url in match:
   So on
```

Please help I'm stuck! cannot do anything with the list it returns except print it, which is useless in its current format

Thanks

Comment: what is `int(my)ints` doing?  What error do you get when you try that?  What kind of "link" are you trying to convert?

Comment: Can you add the full Traceback to your question?

Comment: Sorry that's a typo:
datetime.fromtimestamp(int(match)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Comment: I know the match works fine, if I print priopr to conversion it prints a number, but this number needs converting from unix to date

Comment: When you print `match` does it look something like `['1448204858']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `match` variable looks like `['1448204858']` when printed then it is a *list* containing a single *string* element. `datetime.fromtimestamp()` requires a `float` value, so you need to

- extract the string from the list,
- convert it to a float, and then
- convert that to a datetime:

```python
import re
from datetime import datetime

# test data
link = '"Something":"foo","Date":"1448204858","Otherthing":"bar"'

match=re.compile('"Date":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(match[0]))

print(repr(dt))
print(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Results:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 22, 8, 7, 38)
2015-11-22 08:07:38
```

Comment: Gord!!! Your a legend!

link = Open_URL(url)
match=re.compile('"End Date":"(.+?)"').findall(link)
for url in match:
                   dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(float(match[0]))
                dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Works Perfectly!!!
THANKS so much

Answer (score 0):

I think what you mean by a large number is [UNIX time stamp](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/) also known as `time since epoch`. It can be easily converted to a datetime object in python as so:

```
import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.timestamp(datetime.datetime.now())
print(a)   # 1448206588.806814

b = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(a)
print(b)   # datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 22, 21, 7, 8, 661906)

# using strftime on above object
print(b.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))    #'2015-11-22 21:07:08'
```

Comment: Your right it is a unix date stamp but I cannot convert a list item, error log states it must be a string or number